# How to set Docker Compose `env_file` relative to `.yml` file when multiple `--file` option is used?

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, git-submodules, monorepo

I am trying to set my `env_file` configuration to be relative to each of the multiple `docker-compose.yml` file locations instead of relative to the first `docker-compose.yml`.

The documentation (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file) suggests this should be possible:

> If you have specified a Compose file with docker-compose -f FILE, paths in env_file are relative to the directory that file is in.

For example, when I issue

```
docker compose \
  --file docker-compose.yml \
  --file backend/docker-compose.yml \
  --file docker-compose.override.yml up
```

all of the `env_file` paths in the second (i.e. `backend/docker-compose.yml`) and third (i.e. `docker-compose.override.yml`) are relative to the location of the first file (i.e. `docker-compose.yml`)

I would like to have the `env_file` settings in each `docker-compose.yml` file to be relative to the file that it is defined in.

Is this possible?

Thank you for your time

In case you are curious about the context:

I would like to have a backend repo that is self-contained and the backend developer can just work on it without needing the frontend container.
The frontend repo will pull in the backend repo as a Git submodule, because the frontend container needs the backend container as a dependency.
Here are my 2 repo's:

- backend: https://gitlab.com/starting-spark/porter/backend
- frontend: https://gitlab.com/starting-spark/porter/frontend

The backend is organized like this:

```
/docker-compose.yml
/docker-compose.override.yml
```

The frontend is organized like this:

```
/docker-compose.yml
/docker-compose.override.yml
/backend/ # pulled in as a Git submodule
/backend/docker-compose.yml
/backend/docker-compose.override.yml
```

Everything works if I place my `env_file` inside the `docker-compose.override.yml` file. The backend's override `env_file` will be relative to the backend `docker-compose.yml`. And the frontend's override `env_file` will be relative to the frontend `docker-compose.yml`. The frontend will never use the backend's `docker-compose.override.yml`.

But I wanted to put the backend's `env_file` setting in to the backend's `docker-compose.yml` instead, so that projects needing the backend container can inherit and just use it's defaults. If the depender project wants to override backend's `env_file`, then it can do so in the depender project's `docker-compose.override.yml`.

I hope that makes sense.

If there's another pattern to organizing Docker-Compose projects that handles this scenario, please let me know.

- I did want to avoid a mono-repo.

Comment: The documentation makes it sound like it's *supposed* to work the way you want it to. That's the way I'd want it to work too, so it seems odd that it isn't working that way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that there's already an issue and discussion regarding this:

- https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3874

The thread points out that this is the expected behavior and is documented here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#understanding-multiple-compose-files

> When you use multiple configuration files, you must make sure all paths in the files are relative to the base Compose file (the first Compose file specified with -f). This is required because override files need not be valid Compose files. Override files can contain small fragments of configuration. Tracking which fragment of a service is relative to which path is difficult and confusing, so to keep paths easier to understand, all paths must be defined relative to the base file.

There's a workaround within that discussion that works fairly well:
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3874#issuecomment-470311052

The workaround is to use a ENV var that has a default:

> - ${PROXY:-.}/haproxy/conf:/usr/local/etc/haproxy

Or in my case:

```
  env_file:
    - ${BACKEND_BASE:-.}/.env
```

Hope that can be helpful for others

In case anyone is interested in the full code:
`backend`'s `docker-compose.yml`: https://gitlab.com/starting-spark/porter/backend/-/blob/3.4.3/docker-compose.yml#L13-14
`backend`'s `docker-compose.override.yml`: https://gitlab.com/starting-spark/porter/backend/-/blob/3.4.3/docker-compose.override.yml#L3-4
`backend`'s `.env`: https://gitlab.com/starting-spark/porter/backend/-/blob/3.4.3/.env
`frontend`'s `docker-compose.yml`: https://gitlab.com/starting-spark/porter/frontend/-/blob/3.2.2/docker-compose.yml#L5-6
`frontend`'s `docker-compose.override.yml`: https://gitlab.com/starting-spark/porter/frontend/-/blob/3.2.2/docker-compose.override.yml#L3-4
`frontend`'s `.env`: https://gitlab.com/starting-spark/porter/frontend/-/blob/3.2.2/.env#L16